# regex fails to catch all matches

Tags: java, regex

Here is an example:

```
The two (Senior Officer Stuart & Officer Jess) were intercepted by Officer George.
```

Now, let's say I have two ranks "Officer" and "Senior Officer" and want to
replace the name after them with a general token "PERSON". As you can see there are three names that come after a rank `Stuart, Jess, George`.  I don't know why my regex solution fails to capture all of them. Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "The two (Senior Officer Stuart & Officer Jess) were intercepted by Officer George.";
    ArrayList<String> ranks = new ArrayList<String>();
    ranks.add("Senior Officer");
    ranks.add("Officer");
    for (String rank : ranks) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + rank + " ([a-zA-Z]*?) .*");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(rank);
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is its output:

```
Senior Officer
Stuart
Officer
Stuart
```

which captures Stuart twice (via Senior Officer and Officer), but ignores Jess and George. I am expecting to get this as the output:

```
Senior Officer
Stuart
Officer
Stuart
Officer
Jess
Officer
George
```

Comment: No regex expert, but that space looks suspicious: `([a-zA-Z]*?) .*`

Comment: And yes you should use `while` not `if`

Comment: Something like,,..... `Pattern.compile(".*?" + rank + " ([a-zA-Z]*)");`

Comment: or `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?" + rank + " (\\w*)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be sufficient

```
for (String rank : ranks) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + rank + "\\s+([a-zA-Z]*)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(rank);
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/WdFb2I)**

*Regex Breakdown* (as per comments)

```
Officer #Match Officer literally
 ( #Capturing group
  (?: #Non-capturing group
    \s #Match space
     (?!(?:Senior\s+)?Officer) #Negative lookahead assures that its impossible to match the word Senior(which is optional) and Officer literally
    [A-Z][a-zA-Z]* #Match capital letter followed by combination of capital and small letter
  )* #Repeat the previous step any number of time till one of the condition of first letter being capital fails or word Officer is found
 )
```

Comment: Is there a way to include catching two/three word nouns? For example in "Senior Officer Eduardo Garcia Lopez", to catch the entire "Eduardo Garcia Lopez" instead of the first word "Eduardo"?

Comment: @user3639557 you can do that ..but there is a problem because you can't determine beforehand how many words to capture

Comment: how about, as long as words are upper initial?

Comment: @user3639557 that can be done..but there is another problem, your rank also contains upper initial..so that will be merged which is incorrect

Comment: @user3639557 see if **[this](https://regex101.com/r/gH6aJ3/1)** does help you

Comment: why? assume that ranks do not share words (i.e. in this example ignore "Senior Officer" and only consider "Officer"). Doesn't the matcher work by matching the rank, and then catching the followup words?

Comment: @user3639557 i have pointed above a **[link](https://regex101.com/r/gH6aJ3/2)**..see if its  good

Comment: this seems to work, but looks terribly complicated! ""((?:\s(?!(?:\s+)?Officer)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*)""

Comment: @user3639557 added an explanation

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work as it is promised to work in that link.

Comment: @user3639557 i have hardcoded the regex..see it working **[here](http://ideone.com/V1ZoLK)**

Comment: yeah - but hardcoded ranks don't work for me. I need something that is more generic

Comment: @user3639557 ok give me some time..

Comment: I am not familiar with regex, but wonder why this (".*"+rank + "\\s(([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)+?)") doesn't work?

Comment: @user3639557 check **[here](http://ideone.com/V1ZoLK)**

Comment: @user3639557 `.*` is greedy in nature..so it will consume whole string and match the last part..see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/gH6aJ3/4)**

Comment: I am learning a lot :) ... the solution you referred to involves hardcoded patterns still. What happens if I have 10 new ranks, etc. There must be a simpler solution to this damn problem!

Comment: @user3639557 in that case use alternation in negative lookahead part like 
`(?!(?:rank1|rank2|rank3|....))`

Comment: yeah I was trying it just now - something like this, it still doesn't catch the consecutive words with upperinitial case, but does something "(?!"+rank+") "+rank + "\\s(([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)+?)"

Comment: @user3639557 i am doing a project which I have to show tomorrow. I will update you as soon as I am free..

Comment: thanks man - appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: @user3639557 I created a string `tmp` with alternation for `rank`.this string can be used in negative lookahead..check **[here](http://ideone.com/V1ZoLK)**

Comment: it works, but is awfully slow for longer texts.

Comment: @user3639557 certainly there will be some side effect..

Answer (score 0):

The `for` you are using finds ONLY the first match of each rank. First of all, you need a while clause inside the `for`.

```
 for (String rank : ranks) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rank + " [A-z]+");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(rank);
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
```

However, this does not solve the problem of finding the "senior officer" rank twice: once when you search for "senior officer" and once when you search for "officer". I am not sure how you want to handle this issue. If you want Stuart to appear twice, then this code is good enough. If you want Stuart to be detected only once, you need to work on your regEx.

**P.S.** use an online tool to test the regex before coding it. It saves up a lot of time.

Comment: @user3639557: he's right about using while and not if. 1+

Comment: @user3639557 i have updated the regex